# How to randomly distribute objects only in selected area?

Tags: inkscape

Imagine you wanted to design a glass of soda. First you create a glass:

[image: beaker]
<sup>It's, in fact, a beaker - but that doesn't matter</sup>

Now you copy the object, make it smaller, black and delete the stroke. Then to try to center it in beaker:

[image: full beaker]

Finally, you want some pretty bubbles. How can I randomly distribute them in the brown area, besides copy pasting (which sucks for complicated shapes)?

Comment: I'have no time for a decent answer... give a look to the [spray tool](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/SpecSprayTool) (see also [here](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Spray.html)).

Comment: Bubbles are not random - they form from the imperfections and residue (and ice) inside the glass. The spread and distance from the source of the bubbles is relative to the liquid type and CO2 weight. Difference to fine champagne and Home brand cola when in a glass. I think you could make a brush where the bubbles could be stretched along its length became slightly larger and further apart the higher they traveled up the glass.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let's get a try...

You can create your bubble (sorry, not so pretty):

[image: bubble]

With the bubble selected, press the [spray tool](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/SpecSprayTool) (see also [here](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Spray.html)):

[image: Spray tool]

You can tweak a bit with the tool options until the object are placed according to your wishes:

[image: Tool options]

Now, you can simply keep pressed your left mouse button down and place the bubbles while moving the mouse:

[image: Final image]

With a littler starting bubble and different spray settings:

[image: Alternative image]

Answer (score 13):

You can use *Randomize centers in both dimensions* button under *Rearrange* in the *Align and Distribute* dialog.

1. Select all the objects you want to randomize, then hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and make a single click on the encapsulator object.
2. Open the *Align and Distribute* dialog via *Objects* → *Align and Distribute* menu item (or press <kbd>Ctrl‌‌</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>).
3. Under *Align*, select *Last selected* in the *Relative to* drop down list.
4. Under *Rearrange*, click *Randomize centers in both dimensions* button.

**Sources:**

- [Alignment and Distribution of Objects — A Guide to Inkscape](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Align.html)
- [Align and Distribute — Inkscape — FLOSS Manuals](http://write.flossmanuals.net/inkscape/align-and-distribute/)

Comment: Unfortunately this only seems to work within the bounding box of the shape you are working with and not within the shape itself. Objects appear outside the shape borders.

Comment: seems that randomization works inside borders of current selection rectangle. you can always subtract objects that fell out of desired area...